# How to upload large files to the Firebase Emulator Suite Storage?

Tags: python, firebase, upload, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

For my project I am using the `Firebase Emulator Suite` and the Python library `firebase_admin`. Whenever I am trying to upload a large file (*e.g. > 700 MB zip file*) the file is only uploaded until 104.86 MB and after that it cancels without throwing an error

I have the following zip files which are all over 700 MB large.
[Img: ZIP files in a directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbR8S.png)

This is my `config.yml`:

```
database:
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=<project-id>"
  token_file_path: ""

storage:
  url: "<project-id>.appspot.com"
  token_file_path: ""
```

This are my class variables and the function I am using to upload my file from my local storage.
I already set the environment variable `STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST` to `<storage url ip-addr>` and when I upload smaller files, the files are uploaded to the **local** Firebase Storage (*Firebase Emulator Suite Storage*).

```
def __init__(self, app_name: str = "[DEFAULT]", config_yml_path: str = "config.yml"):
        configs = FileUtils.load_config_yml(config_yml_path)
        self.DEBUG = bool(configs["environment"]["debug"])
        self.DATABASE_URL = configs["database"]["url"]
        self.BUCKET_URL = configs["storage"]["url"]
        
        if self.DEBUG:
                    os.environ["STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = "<storage url ip-addr>"

        
        self.APP_OBJ = firebase_admin.initialize_app(
                            credential=token,
                            options={
                                "databaseURL": self.DATABASE_URL,
                                "storageBucket": self.BUCKET_URL,
                            },
                            name=app_name)

        self.BUCKET = storage.bucket()

        


def upload_zip_from_path(self, zip_path:str):
        zip_name = zip_path.split("/")[-1]  # "test/abc.zip" -> ["test", "abc.zip"] -> "abc.zip"
        # Get a reference to the Firebase Storage bucket
        zip_folder = self.BUCKET.blob(f"zip/{zip_name}")
        zip_folder.upload_from_filename(zip_path)    
        return zip_folder.public_url
```

After the partly upload the 'public' URL will be returned successfully.

It seems like only 104.86 MB can be uploaded from the zip files before the upload cancels. I downloaded the file via the Firebase Emulator UI (`http://localhost:4000/storage/<project-id>.appspot.com`) and it is clearly not possible to open it.

But when I uploaded a zip containing a video with ~108 MB using the Firebase Emulator UI the file was uploaded without a problem and even after downloading the zip I had no issues playing the containing video.
[Img: Firebase Emulator UI Storage (ZIP files uploaded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfDUK.png)
[Img: Firebase Emulator UI Storage (108 MB file uploaded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2DQU.png)

I found nothing about maximum file upload size for the Firebase Emulator Suite's Storage.

I tried to upload the files by hand using the Firebase Emulator UI but the upload does not work. No spinning progress indicator is shown like with smaller files.

Also I seperated the chunks and tried to upload the file as bytes to the storage but still the same result: exactly 104.86 MB uploaded.

My next guess was to see if I could upload files using Flutter I have not found a way to configure the FirebaseApp in Flutter for Linux because FlutterFire does not support Linux so far...